# SQL Server, update query to remove square brackets in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, brackets

In a field of one table of my DB I found a lot of rubbish, especially "[" and "(".
I found a way to select the rows (Titolo LIKE '%[%'  ESCAPE '\').

But I can't find a way to replace these chars with space ' '.
I tried

```
SET Titolo = replace(Titolo, '\[', '')
```

in some ways, but the field don't change.

Comment: You don'y need to escape [ in the replace function: `replace(Titolo, '[', '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square brackets need escaping only when you search for them with the [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator, because they are wildchars.
So no need to escape them inside `replace()`:

```
update tablename
set Titolo = replace(Titolo, '[', '')
where Titolo like '%\[%' escape '\'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98f5408cf63a7de975f503f4aee6879e)**

```
update tablename SET Titolo = replace(Titolo, '[', '')
```